# Create a Symfony form drop-down list with two properties

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

I'm trying to make a Symfony form with a drop-down list which use two properties.

Let me explain :
I have a SparePart entity with two properties :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CM\PlatformBundle\Entity\Supplier")
*/
private $supplier;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CM\PlatformBundle\Entity\SupplierGroup")
*/
private $supplierGroup;
```

I want to let the user chose between either one direct supplier or a group of supplier, like this :

1. ----DIRECT SUPPLIERS----

   - Michelin
   - Continental
2. ----GROUP OF SUPPLIERS----

   - European suppliers
   - American suppliers

I don't know how to handle this kind of situation in the form builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your form as a service (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services) and you inject the entity manager in it.
Before building your form, you query your repository to fetch your suppliers.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $suppliers = $this->em->repository->findAll();

        //loop through your results to build an array

        $builder
            …
        ;
    }
```

Build an array matching this pattern

```
$arrSuppliers[$groupName] = array($supplierId => $supplierName);
```

And then you can do this to create your list:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#grouping-options

Comment: Thank you Hakim, I will give it a try ASAP.

Comment: I managed to create the array outside of the form type, I simply pass it through the $options argument.
However, I don't know how to add my array in my form. Can you show me an exemple please ?

Comment: if your array is correctly formed this 
    `$builder->add('stockStatus', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices' => $yourArray)
    );`
should work

Comment: Thanks ! Finally got it ! I just had trouble because it was a non-mapped field, so I had to add : `->add('supplierr', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => $suppliersList,"mapped" => false,))`
Now, I will have fun to validate this :p